# How to change the logo of my wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, resize

I wonder if you could help with a problem i'm having. Ive made a child theme from the Lightly theme and its all good except I need the logo to be 580 x 282. I've been messing with the css and can get it to that size however the image is blurry as it's using the cropped version.

When it asks me to crop i just expand the cropping field to make it fit the uploaded image.

How can I make it use the original uncropped image? I've been messing with firebug and if I just remove the cropped-logo1.jpg to just logo.jpg it works fine but from what I can tell you cant edit that code as it doesn't show up in the header.php file.

kind Regards

Karri

Comment: sorry, might have been useful to link the site.

its : http://www.alienmilkshakes.com

Comment: booooooooooooooooom

done it. most probably wrong but what do you think?

got rid of the image, used a css background image instead. Still have the title and slug line but moved them way off the screen.

Can you guys let me know if it looks ok please?