# Wordpress: I can't change the logo image of my site

Tags: css, wordpress, resize

First of all: I've already looked on [How to change the logo of my wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208152/how-to-change-the-logo-of-my-wordpress-site) and I didn't found any useful information for my problem.

In the picture you see the costume logo picture...

[image]

...and I change it, if the screen size gets smaller, with this new image:

[image]

To replace the image I must write

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){


        .logo-wrapper > .logo > img {
            background-image: url('wp-content/uploads/2017/06/new_logo.png')!important;
    }
}
```

But the old logo is still seen in the homepage and covered with a part of the new logo:

[image]

Comment: Are you using any custom theme or responsive menu plugin ?

Comment: Maybe there is a text div with blue background.. please provide site link..

Comment: Please provide the site link. so that i can say exact solution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old logo is probably still seen because it comes from the IMG-tag. Which will have a '*src="path-to-image"*'

In your CSS, you're setting the background of the IMG-tag to 'new_logo.png' but the IMG might still hold an image as well.

Honestly, I'm not familiar with WP code structure, but you should look at the code where the IMG-tag resides or is generated. That's where you'll have to make some modifications to change the way the default logo is displayed to also be a CSS background so that your media-query would work/override default upon resolution change.

It could be something like this:

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <a class="logo" href="<?php someCodeToGetUrl()">
        <img src="<?php getLogoUrl(); ?>" />
    </a>
</div>
```

A potential change could be:

```
<div class="logo-wrapper">
    <a class="logo" href="<?php someCodeToGetUrl()">
        <span style="background-image: url('<?php getLogoUrl(); ?>')"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

At which point your media query should work. It may require some additional CSS for sizing/positioning etc.

Hope this helps. I'm sorry that I couldn't be of more help. I don't have enough time to install WP and check out the code for a more accurate example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try checking for logo option in "Customize" section on top of admin bar.
2. Check header.php file for logo  tag and change URL of that.